# How do you do a conditional format for a date range

Tags: google-spreadsheets

I have a list in a spreadsheet of upcoming game releases. I'd like to do conditional formatting on the `Release Date` field so that if the game is being released this month / week, I can have different formatting applied. So far though, all I can find are set checks like `today`, `tomorrow`, `yesterday`, etc.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

There is a little ambiguity about "this week" so I have chosen week number (which may give rise to some anomalies at year end) but for most purposes the following should work in new Google Sheets:

[image: SU784856 example]

where the two formulae are:

```
=and(year(today())=year(A1),weeknum(A1)=weeknum(today()))
```

for orange (week) and for yellow (month):

```
=and(year(today())=year(A1),month(A1)=month(today()))
```

where the relevant dates are assumed to be in ColumnA.